# Graphical designer for asp.net controls

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-interface, controls, ascx

I'm searching a graphical designer, better than visual studio designer for asp.net typical and ajax controls. Visual studio designer (VS 2010 B2) very often don't handle with html code and shows nothing.
Is there any better tool for writing code behind and design graphically controls for asp.net web sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit that I didn't find any better tool than Visual Studio Designer. All of them not always handle all html code, especially connected with asp.net ajax controls.
Same behavior you can expect from Microsofr Expression Web 3. :( So there is not any good answer for my question, or I don't know any right. So the topic is closed for now because anybody wants answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Expression Web 3](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx)

Comment: What is the difference between Web 2 and Web 3?

Comment: The major difference would be the target .Net framework ... Expression Web 4 is also now out - for Visual Studio 2010, .Net framework 4.0.

This information is easily googled :)